# HStack Layout issue in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can I align the values of individuals of HStack with respect to others?

I want to start with both "SwiftUI" text should be aligned with leading.

So, "Title" & "Description" should have the same width, but I don't want a fixed width solution.

[image]

Comment: Fix width is the solution but Try Once "Grid" & "GridRow"